# SMS Intent not populating recipient only in oneplus mobiles

Tags: java, android

After google policy changed to not use SEND_SMS. I am using sms intent to send sms with custom message and sender address auto populated. It work in almost all mobile. But only in oneplus mobiles, receipent address is not getting populated

private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    {
        String defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(getActivity());
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        sendIntent.putExtra("address",phoneNumber);
        sendIntent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);

        if (defaultSmsPackageName != null)
        {
            sendIntent.setPackage(defaultSmsPackageName);
        }
        startActivity(sendIntent);

    }
    else
    {
        Intent smsIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        smsIntent.putExtra("address",phoneNumber);
        smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body",message);
        startActivity(smsIntent);
    }

}
```

I also tried

```
            Intent sendIntent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
            sendIntent.putExtra("address",phoneNumber);
            sendIntent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);
            sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + phoneNumber));

and 


            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.putExtra("address", phoneNumber);
            intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + phoneNumber));
            intent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);
```

None are working in oneplus mobiles(3, 7 and 7 pro). It is working in all MI phone, Samsung, Nokia, Honor, Motorola, Lenovo etc. Only in oneplus phone having issue.

Comment: I am having same issue. Have you found any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

[image]
[image]

I have tried below and it successfully worked for me. Tested on One Plus 3t.

```
            String phoneNumber="+91xxxxxxxxxx";
            String message ="Hi ABZ";
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" + phoneNumber));
            intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
            startActivity(intent);[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```